# Как выбрать элементы DataFrame, если элемент принадлежит списку?

Tags: python, pandas

Как сделать, чтобы выбирались только элементы с CSV принадлежащие списку?

```
Hello = pd.read_csv('players_18.csv')

Teams = pd.Series(['AS Monaco','Paris Saint-Germain','Olympique Lyonnais','Olympique de Marseille',' OGC Nice','AS Saint-Étienne',' FC Girondins de Bordeaux',
'Toulouse Football Club','Stade Rennais FC','FC Nantes','Montpellier HSC','En Avant de Guingamp','LOSC Lille','Stade Malherbe Caen'
,'Amiens SC','Angers SCO','Dijon FCO','FC Metz','RC Strasbourg Alsace','ESTAC Troyes'])

Hello = Hello[Hello['club'] in Teams ]
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Hello = Hello.query('club in @Teams')
```

или так:

```
Hello = Hello.loc[Hello['club'].isin(Teams)]
```